# runtime error (NZEC) Java SPOJ

Tags: java, runtime-error, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to do a SPOJ problem called Prime Generator. Although the output works on my computer it doesn't work when I try to run it on SPOJ. The following error message occurs.

Error: runtime error (NZEC)

Can you help me find what it is?

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.Scanner;


class Prime_generator {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    int number_of_entries=input.nextInt();
    int [] entries=new int[number_of_entries*2];

    for(int i=0;i<number_of_entries*2;i++){
        entries[i]=input.nextInt();
    }


    BitSet bits=new BitSet(1000000002);

    bits.set(0, 1000000000);
    bits.set(0,false);
    bits.set(1,false);
    for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(1000000001);i++){

        if(bits.get(i)){

            for(int j=2;j*i<=100000000;j++){

            bits.set(j*i, false);

                }
        }

    }   

    int i=0;

    int starting_index=0;
    int ending_index=0;

    int array_index=0;
    while(i<number_of_entries){

        starting_index=entries[array_index];
        ending_index=entries[array_index+1];
        array_index+=2;
        for(int k=starting_index;k<=ending_index;k++){
            if(bits.get(k)){

                System.out.println(k);
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }


    System.exit(0);


}
```

}

Comment: maybe it runs too long,so that the timer expires and thus your code does not return 0.

Comment: it ran within the allotted time

Comment: @user35265 you can't assign large number like 10^9 ..

Comment: To which part are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Some points that must be noted:

- You must use fast I/O, i.e., [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) classes instead of [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (take a look at [this blog post](https://algocoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/fast-io-methods-for-competitive-programming/)).
- Pre-process the prime numbers before reading the input (otherwise you would pre-compute the complete solution several times).
- Do not forget to close your input stream(s) before you exit the *main* method. This avoids the *resource leak* warning.